# Why isn't the order updating when something is added to the cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, cart, edit-order

I've created an order for the customer's cart using the following code (When the customer clicks checkout on the app we're making):

```
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
$order = $service->getOrder();
```

However, when a product is added/removed to the cart, the order items remain the same as before the update. How am I supposed to handle the update to the order? Do I cancel all orders the cart has and create a new one? Or is there a way to properly update the order when a new item is added to the cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completed quote is known as an order. When you add add/remove a product to cart, the changes is applying only to quotes. There is no role for order in cart.

When you checkout and then place order (in this case `submitAll()`) only an order is come into action. Once order is created, then you cant alter it's charateristics by adding/removing again to the cart. By that, you can only create a new order.

Comment: Is that how I'm supposed to do it? Cancel  the previous orders and make a new one? Or am I doing something wrong?